# Superscripts in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, superscripts

I have some lines in a verbatim environment

```
...
\begin{verbatim}
    line 1
    * line 2
    line 3
    * line 4
    line 5
\end{verbatim}
...
```

at the beginning of some lines I want to add a number in superscript. I've indicated that with asterisks now. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `numbers` option from the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document} 

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If the numbers must appear as superscript, add the following to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textsuperscript{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
```

Now that the original question has been edited, you can use the `commandchars` option to introduce escape sequences in verbatim code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document} 

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
First verbatim line.
\textsuperscript{1}Second verbatim line.
Third verbatim line.
\textsuperscript{2}Fourth verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**  Don't know why I did not see earlier that you wanted to use numbers instead of just an asterix. Here is a version that allows you to use `^1` to get a superscript added with the given number to yield:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{myVerbatimStyle} {
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\ttfamily\kern-0.1ex\textsuperscript]{^}{\ },
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myVerbatimStyle]
   line 1
  ^1 line 2
   line 4
  ^2 line 5
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Note that this does require you to leave a space as in `^1 line`. If you do not like that another option is to use `^` character on both sides and change the `moredelim` line to read:

```
moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\ttfamily\kern-0.1ex\textsuperscript]{^}{^},
```

In this case you would use `^1^line`, but I think the one with the space is better.

---

Here is a revised solution using [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/), which will automatically superscript the asterix for you, and also add a color to make it stand out:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{myVerbatimStyle} {
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    otherkeywords={*},
    morekeywords={*},
    keywordstyle={\color{red}\ttfamily\kern-0.1ex\textsuperscript},
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myVerbatimStyle]
   line 1
  *line 2
   line 3
  *line 4
   line 5
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

---

**Old Solution:** With [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) you can use `mathescape=true`, which means that you can enclose any math within a `$...$` and it will get formatted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
    line 1
    ${}^\ast$ line 2
    line 3
    ${}^\ast$ line 4
    line 5
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good alternative. Perhaps add the option of making the formatting similar to the `verbatim` environment by using `basicstyle=\ttfamily`. Additionally, compare the left margin with that of the `verbatim` environment. Anything to emulate the `verbatim` environment exactly? I know, I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: @Werner: Good points. See updated solution.