# Boldface and subscripts in verbatim mode?

Tags: verbatim, bold, subscripts

How do I create boldface and subscripts in verbatim mode? I've seen mention of a `fancyvrb` package that might be able to help. Can anyone provide working LaTeX code, either with or without `fancyvrb`?

Comment: Look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33236/superscripts-in-verbatim-environment

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the `fancyvrb` package, with the `commandchars` option you can introduce escape sequences in verbatim code; in particular, you can get boldfaced fonts (provided you are using a suitable font. Using the `codes` option you can specify catcode changes ; in particualr, this allows you to include formatted mathematics in verbatim text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{bera}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`_=8}]
code line 1
$a_{i}$
code line 2
\textbf{boldfaced text}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the more powerful [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, you can escape to LaTeX using the `escapeinside` option and you can activate the `mathescape` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bera}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
escapeinside={||},
mathescape=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
code line 1
$a_{i}$
code line 2
|\textbf{boldfaced text}|
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above solutions treted subscripts as mathematical expressions; you can get non-math subscripts using `\textsubscript` from the `fixltx2e` package; a little example using `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{bera}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`_=8}]
code line 1
$a_{i}$
code line 2
\textbf{boldfaced text}
a\textsubscript{i}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the working code. I noticed the subscripts require math mode. Is there any way to keep subscripts in the same fixed-width font (e.g. Courier) as the verbatim, non-math text?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 sure; please see the last code in my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I need to figure out what those 'catcode' sequences mean. Are those from the fancyvrb package?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Catcodes come from TeX. All characters in TeX are assigned a "category code" or catcode. Normal characters are catcode 11; this category normally comprises all of the letter characters. Some special characters have other catcode which means they are not treated as a normal letter. Internally `fancyvrb` "annihilates" special catcodes to treat all characters as normal letters. When you use the option `\catcode`_=8`, for example, you are instructing `fancyvrb` to treat the underscore not as a regular letter, but as the special character used to introduce subscripts.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 A detailed explanation on catcodes can be found in [TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html). Please, don't forget to accept my answer if you consider that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `alltt` package, which offers an `alltt` environment that is like `verbatim`, except that `\{}` are still metacharacters. Remember that subscripts and superscripts are also available via `\sb` and `\sp` and `$...$` can also be written as `\(...\)`, so you don't need `$`, `_` and `^` as (unavailable) metacharacters.

Example (from slide 19 [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2223/TeX+MATLAB/latex-slides.pdf#page=20)):

```latex
\begin{alltt}
  for \(i:=1,\ldots,n\)
    print \(x\sb{i}\sp{2}\)
\end{alltt}
```